# native Array Reduce Implementation issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to implement Native reduce:

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, initialVal) {
    var accumulator = (initialVal === undefined) ? undefined : initialVal;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (accumulator !== undefined)
            accumulator = callback.call(undefined, accumulator, this[i], i, this);
        else
            accumulator = this[i];
    }
    return accumulator;
};
```

Most of the tests run fine, but when I try running this it fails:

**Original Reduce:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce((carry, val, i, arr) => { console.log('arr', arr); arr[arr.length] = val; return carry;  }, []);

// Iterated 5 times
arr (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr (6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
arr (7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
arr (8) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
arr (9) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Myreduce:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5].myReduce((carry, val, i, arr) => { console.log('arr', arr); arr[arr.length] = val; return carry;  }, []);

// Infinite recursion, since we are pushing every time
arr (5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr (6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
arr (7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
arr (8) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
arr (9) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
arr (10) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr (11) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Can someone enlighten me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: compare your code with *working code* on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Polyfill

Answer (score 3):

You mutate the original array, so `this.length` is never reached.

You should have stored the length of the original array somewhere and use it instead.

Eg:

```
Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, initialVal) {
    var accumulator = (initialVal === undefined) ? undefined : initialVal;
    var len = this.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (accumulator !== undefined)
            accumulator = callback.call(undefined, accumulator, this[i], i, this);
        else
            accumulator = this[i];
    }
    return accumulator;
};
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++)`